# Diffie-Hellman key agreement on do phase, incompatible parameters

Tags: java, diffie-hellman

I send a Diffie-Hellman public key in a byte array through a socket and store it in a file, when I need the key I transform it using the key factory but when I'm going to combine my private key and the public key of my partner on key agreement, the `doPhase` function it give me a exception of incompatible parameters.

```java
    public byte[] createMac(byte[] fileBytes, String nick){
        byte[] mac = null;
        byte[] digest;
        try {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
            md.update(fileBytes);
            digest = md.digest();
            
            KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("DH");
            
            byte[] myPrivateKey = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(dirMyKeys+"//dhPrivateKey.txt"));
            PrivateKey dhPrivKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(myPrivateKey));
            

            byte[] myPublicKey = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(dirKeys+"/"+nick+"DhPublicKey.txt"));
            System.out.println(dirKeys+"/"+nick+"DhPublicKey.txt");
            PublicKey dhPubKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(new X509EncodedKeySpec(myPublicKey));
            
            SecretKey secretKey = combine(dhPrivKey, dhPubKey);
            
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
            System.out.println( "\nStart decryption" );
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
            mac = cipher.doFinal(digest);
            System.out.println( "Finish decryption: " );
            
            return mac;
            
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | IOException | InvalidKeySpecException | InvalidKeyException | IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException | NoSuchPaddingException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Client.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return mac;
    }
    
    private static SecretKey combine(PrivateKey private1, PublicKey public1) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException  {
        KeyAgreement ka = KeyAgreement.getInstance("DH");
        ka.init(private1);
        //error on this line
        ka.doPhase(public1, true);
        SecretKey secretKey = ka.generateSecret("DES");
        return secretKey;
    }
```

This is the exception:

```
java.security.InvalidKeyException: Incompatible parameters
        at com.sun.crypto.provider.DHKeyAgreement.engineDoPhase(DHKeyAgreement.java:199)
        at javax.crypto.KeyAgreement.doPhase(KeyAgreement.java:567)
        at safetalk_client.Client.combine(Client.java:279)
        at safetalk_client.Client.createMac(Client.java:260)
        at safetalk_client.Client.sendFile(Client.java:234)
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have experience with the api, but it sounds like its expecting a different input type. There is a specific type of private and public key class for diffie-Hellman, maybe its needs those instead of the more generic sounding publickey and privatekey classes:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/interfaces/DHPublicKey.html

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/interfaces/DHPrivateKey.html

let me know if it works.